# GenericStruct In CppContainer

Tags: c++, templates, generics

how would you make the two lines generic without using std::any?
Thanks.

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        struct C
        {
            uint32_t ID = 0;
            uint32_t Mode = 0;          // <<<<<<-------- make generic
            uint32_t Value = 0;         // <<<<<<-------- make generic
         };
        std::vector<C> moves;
    };
    std::queue<B> PreparedMoves;
};
```

I am open for any suggestions.
Thanks

Mode and Value shall be any primitive type.

Comment: Make `A` template?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic"? Do you have a list of possible types, or want to use any type? What are you actually trying to do? Please add additional context to the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by generic in this case?

Comment: Sorry i thought that would be implicit clear. I will use for Mode and Value any type. ("without using std::any"). With template i couldn't figure it out. The answer from @aschepler was my frist thought too. But than everything is from the same type inside the template.

Comment: On c++17 and higher i would just use std::any for solve my problem. But i got a specific project which i can't uprade and have to use c++14.

Comment: Also i could implement a short kind of std::any, but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: How about `boost::any`?

Comment: Can't bring the overhead of boost into the project, but good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
template <typename ModeType, typename ValueType>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        struct C
        {
            uint32_t  ID = 0;
            ModeType  Mode = ModeType{};
            ValueType Value = ValueType{};
        };
        std::vector<C> moves;
    };
    std::queue<B> PreparedMoves;
};
```

A template parameter is visible in the class scope of nested classes. Note `A<T1, T2>::B` and `A<T3, T4>::B` are different types (assuming `T1` is not `T3` or `T2` is not `T4`), and similarly for the nested `C` types.

The original specific `A` is now called `A<uint32_t, uint32_t>`. If the type of `Mode` and `Value` should always be identical, you only need one template parameter.

Comment: Not working for me, your  answer was my first idea too.

Comment: That's a matter of how you use it. If you need a shared type for some part of this, maybe some type erasure pattern can help. (`std::any` is the ultimate type erasure, but it's usually nicer to do something more specific to keep using the data easier.)